# Equivalente ao REGEXP_REPLACE do Oracle no SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server-2012

Em minha aplicação preciso retirar as palavras comuns de strings
do banco de dados, tais como: DE PARA COM DA

Que são palavras de ligação e não tem grande importância na caracterização
do item em si.

Digamos o item:

> CASA DE COMANDO

Eu posso facilmente retirar o `DE` assim:

```
REPLACE( 'CASA DE COMANDO, ' DE ', ' ' )
```

Mas como o `' DE '` está entre dois brancos se ele aparecer 
no inicio ou no final esse `replace` não funcionará.
Então eu substituo o comando por algum assim:

```
   REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 'CASA DE COMANDDO, ' DE ', ' ' ), ' DE', ' ' ), 'DE ', ' ' )
```

Ele retira a palavra comum quando estiver entre os espaços, estiver no final ou no inicio.

O problema é que se uma palavra começar ou terminar com *DE* ele retirará também. Preciso que o 
`replace` respeite a palavra inteira e não apenas parte dela.

No **ORACLE** eu resolvi com **REGEXP_REPLACE**, mas não consegui achar algo similar nativo
no **SQLSERVER**.

Escrever uma **UDF** para resolver está meio fora de cogitação porque é a rotina toda faz muitas
comparações entre as strings e demora bastante, se eu adicionar ainda mais esse tempo tenho medo
de inviabilizar o programa.

Alguém já resolveu essa questão e pode me ajudar?

Comment: Aqui o teu problema requer uma melhor explicação.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova Eu penso que a explicação basta. Eu preciso trocar a palavra DE sem trocar a parte de uma palavra que contenha DE Por exemplo, TANQUE DE DECANTAÇÃO. Preciso trocar apenas o primeiro DE. A função deve retornar  TANQUE DECANTAÇÃO. Isso esta explicado na questão e é só isso. Obs: E não fui eu quem negativou sua resposta.

Comment: Fico com a sensação de falta info, não é a explicação do replace, isso acho que ficou claro, falta sim do contexto, por exemplo, vais utilizar então num SQL JOB, periodicamente e precisas de criar uma SP, ou por cada entrada que recebes queres fazer o replace, ou queres em consultas numa VIEW fazer este replace e mostrar as strings com o formato que queres e nunca mudas os dados na base de dados. Falas numa rotina, mas corre quando, de 10 em 10 minutos ou durante a noite, pecebes isso faz muita diferença.

Comment: É impressão sua. Se você me resolver como eu ffaço o SELECT REPLACE( ... eu poderei usar em qualquer coisa. De fato, esse replace deve fazer parte de uma função. Eu passo a string para a função e ela me devolve a string limpa, sem essas palavras de ligação.

Answer (score 0):

Criei essa função para resolver o problema acima. O `REGEX_REPLACE` do Oracle
foi desmembrado em 3 replaces para atingir o mesmo objetivo.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON


GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Reginaldo Rigo>
-- Create date: <30/03/2020>
-- Description: <Retirar todas as palavras comum constantes na tabela de palavras comum
-- da string que for passada como parametro.>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION retiracomuns
(
    @strlimpa varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @palavra varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE palavras CURSOR FOR select palavra from PALAVRASCOMUNS
    OPEN palavras
    FETCH NEXT FROM palavras INTO @palavra
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 

        /*
        //   Essa parte em Oracle 

        strlimpa := REGEXP_REPLACE( strlimpa, '(^|\s)' || rec.palavra || '(\s|$)',' ');
        //
        */


       /* Foi substituida por essa em SQLSERVER */ 

       /* trato o primeiro caso particular quando a string começa com a palavra comum */
       IF PATINDEX( @palavra + ' %', @strlimpa ) > 0 
          set @strlimpa = SUBSTRING( @strlimpa, len(@palavra) + 2, LEN( @strlimpa ))


        /* trato o segundo caso particular quando a string termina com a palavra comum */
       IF PATINDEX( '% ' + @palavra, @strlimpa ) > 0 
           set @strlimpa = SUBSTRING( @strlimpa, 1,  PATINDEX( '% ' + @palavra, @strlimpa ))

       /* aqui posso usar o replace normal */
       /* como a palavra esta em dois espaços a função replace não irá mexer em outros lugares */
       set @strlimpa = RTRIM( LTRIM( REPLACE( @strlimpa, ' ' + @palavra + ' ', ' ' )))


       FETCH NEXT FROM palavras INTO @palavra 
    END
    CLOSE palavras
    DEALLOCATE palavras



    RETURN @strlimpa

END
GO
```